# createObjectURL mobile browser support requirement - "with URL prefixed as webkitURL"

Tags: javascript

Going through MDN web docs for createObjectURL (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL), one can see under **Browser Compatibility** (mobile) that this method is only supported by various mobile browser `with URL prefixed as webkitURL`.

I'm not really sure what that means. Can someone explain (with an illustrative example) what needs to be done to support these mobile browsers?

Comment: use `(window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL()`

Comment: Note that this MDN article seems a bit outdated, according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls), only *UC for Android* needs the prefix.

Comment: @Kaiido: true, but I mostly look at `show all` when I use caniuse, to see how previous versions of a browser fare. Specifically the Android browser's version 4.1 and 4.3 are edge cases I had in mind when I asked this question. Too bad the only answer is downvoted and there's no reliable answer yet.

Comment: @dandavis comment is actually the correct *safe* way. I did downvote the other answer because it was blatantly broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means you have to use `webkitURL` when you want to call `URL.createObjectURL`. It's a vendor prefix like the `-webkit-`CSS vendor prefixes.

```
var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var createObjectURL = URL.createObjectURL || webkitURL.createObjectURL;
```

Comment: Ah finally. And the second line is useless since you already mapped `webkitURL` to `URL` the line before.

Comment: Are there are other vendors for that like `mozURL.createObjectURL`, `msURL.createObjectURL`, `oURL.createObjectURL`?